# Minimizing chi-squared to find unknown value of parameters

Tags: probability-or-statistics, mathematical-optimization

```
X= 
 Sum[(events[[i]] - f[x, a, b])^2/
  events[[i]], {i, 1, 40}]
```

I want to minimize X to find the value of a and b. How will i do it?

Comment: Look at [`FindFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html), [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html), and related functions.

Comment: You're not using the usual chi-square statistic.  The denominator ought to be the "expected value" which I assume is `f[a, a, b]` (with the observed counts being `events`).  In other words, what happens when `events[[i]] == 0` and `f[x, a, b] > 0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not write the function definition, write the real function and summation would also include *x*. Then use the function `FindMinimum[X,{a,b}]`